# How to use widgets in django-filter fields?

Tags: python, html, django, django-filter

Wanted to set widgets
`"class":"form-control"`
to django-filter fields.

**filters.py**

```
from django_filters import FilterSet,DateFilter,CharFilter,DateFromToRangeFilter
from django_filters.widgets import RangeWidget,CSVWidget,DateRangeWidget
from django import forms
from .models import Blog

class BlogFilter(FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name="created_at",lookup_expr='gte',label='From date',
        widget=DateFromToRangeFilter(attrs={
            'placeholder':'YYYY/MM/DD',
            'class':'form-control'
            })
    )
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name="created_at",lookup_expr='lte',label='To date')

    blog_name = CharFilter(field_name="blog_name",lookup_expr='icontains',label='Blog Name',
        widget=TextWidgets(attrs={
            'class':'form-control'
        })
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('category','status','user')
```

tried to write widget in meta class also but didn't work.

1. Which widget to be used for `CharFilter`? (like we use `forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}` in django forms)
2. Which widget to be used for `DateFilter`?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is with a template filter.

So in the template for the filter I'd do something like this;

```
{% for field in filter.form %}
    {{ field|htmlattributes:"class: form-control" }}
{% endfor %}
```

And the filter does this;

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def htmlattributes(value, arg):
    """ Allows adding of attributes to tagged form elements. """
    attrs = value.field.widget.attrs
    components = arg.split(',')

    for string in components:
        key, values_string = string.split(':')
        values = values_string.strip()

        if attrs.get(key):
            values = attrs.get(key) + ' ' + values

        attrs.update({key: values})

    rendered = str(value)
    return rendered
```

Given your comment... you need to load template tags/filters, just like static etc which I'll assume you've done.

Just put a `{% load x %}` at the top of the template to load `htmlattributes` from wherever you put it.

To read up on how to write your own template tags and filters the documentation can be found here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: `TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/
Invalid filter: 'htmlattributes'` Got this error

Comment: @AjayKhajindar Did you load it? I'd suggest you didn't

Comment: `TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/
'x' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
rest_framework
static
tz`

Comment: No you load from whatever module you put it in. Not `x`, that's just an example.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with load module which is used to load html attribute. Do I need to import it? I tried this `{% load 'htmlattibutes' %}` but didn't work.

Comment: You need to put it in a file & load that file

Comment: too confusing ans.

Comment: Expecting proper solution without keeping any confusion.

Comment: @AjayKhajindar I've added a link to the docs for writing your own template tags & filters. You'll find this knowledge useful because it'll let you do a lot more with context data in your templates.